# use 'mail' to read email from command line

Tags: bash, scripting, mailx

I know we can use `mail` command in terminal to start using the `mail` program in interactive mode.

However, I want to read the email using `mail` command non-interactively.

Is  there a command like

```
$ mail -optionToReadMail -mailNumber 1;
```

which will display the content of email in stdout ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To print the first mail message in your default mailbox, use:

```
echo p | mail
```

`mail` is only interactive when stdin is a terminal.  Because `mail` gets its stdin from a pipe, it is non-interactive.  The `p` command (print) tells it to print the default (first) message.

For more options, you may find that `man mail` is very helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using pipe ??

Comment: @sps Sure.  Use a here-string:  `mail <<<p`.

Comment: Is there a way without using the `<` character ?

Comment: To help me answer that, please explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Why are pipes and `<` unwanted?

Comment: pipe and redirection operator are filtered ... it is a challenge that i am trying to solve... however as you have answered what i asked in original post i have marked it answered ...

Comment: @sps In the future, put all your conditions in your question upfront, instead of adding them piecemeal after the question has been answered.

Comment: Do you know how to extract specific parts like the subject, from, to, body, etc...?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I'm sure that there are other ways but a simple one would be: `echo p | mail | grep ^Subject:`